# Android/SQLite - Storage Location of Files

Tags: android, sqlite, android-source, gcov

I am working on a test of an Android application that runs the SQLite methods in the Android API. I would like to get code coverage of the SQLite code in the Android Open Source Project (AOSP), and I have it set up to run G-Cov and save that coverage information when I run my test. However, I have no idea where this coverage information is stored. I assumed it would be in `data/data/package-name`, but I don't see anything, and I couldn't successfully pull all of my files off of the Android emulator.

Does anyone know where this file will be stored? I'm not sure if it is stored with SQLite or on the emulator (which is where I assume, as I did not see it in the SQLite directory).

Thanks.

EDIT: Specifically, I am looking for *.gcno and *.gcda files.

EDIT: Now I'm thinking they have to be on a shared library on the emulator, although in File Explorer (I am using Eclipse Juno with ADT), I see nothing close to `/lib/*` and `/data/data/package-name/lib` is empty. Anyone know where that location could be?

Answer (score 0):

is in data/data/ nothing?

when this folder is empty, maybe try sqlite manager for eclipse

Comment: It's not empty by any means. My database is the application's data, and my test shows up (although the library is empty). What will SQLite Manager do, anyways?

Comment: SQLite Manager shows the database of your app. Look at google to find something about this manager. It helps a lot.